# Springboot - AWS Elasticbeanstalk - Resource cannot be resolved

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, filenotfoundexception

Does anyone knows how to read a file from the resource folder when the application is running on the AWS Elasticbeanstalk?

Please see code below:

```
Resource resource = new ClassPathResource("application.properties");
File file = resource.getFile();
Map propsMap = PropertyUtil.readProperties(file);
```

[image]

This is the error message:

java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [application.properties] cannot be resolved to absolute file path because it does not reside in the file system: jar:file:/var/app/current/application.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/application.properties"

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The path in the exception looks correct. Can you open the `jar` file and confirm the file is there (in `BOOT-INF/classes/application.properties`). As the error could be in the maven configuration which might not be packing the properties file in the correct place. And does the app run correctly when you fire it manually on your computer? (as I assume it should trigger the same error). And last but not least, if the app runs ok on your computer, are you deploying the **exact** same jar file that you produce to EBS?

Comment: Yes the app run correctly when I fire it on my computer. Yes I deployed the same jar and the content is ok, it does content the resource folder with all files. I wonder if it is because I deployed on the AWS the access to the files may work different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably just change your PropertyUtil to be able to read from the InputStream:

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
try (InputStream stream =
           new ClassPathResource("application.properties").getInputStream()) {
    properties.load(stream);
}
```

`Properties` class is already a `Map` implementation so you wouldn't need to change any other code.